# How to Scheduling a Pipeline in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I followed the tutorials of MS and created a pipeline to move data from the on premise SQL Tablet to Azure Blob and then there's another pipeline to move the blob data to azure sql table. From the document provided, I need to specify the active period (start time and end time) for the pipeline and everything run well.

The question is what can I do if I want the pipeline to be activated every 3 hours, until I manually stop the operation. Currently I need to change the start time and end time in the json script and publish it again everyday and I think there should be another way to do it.

I'm new to azure, any help/comment will be appreciate, thank you.

p.s. I can't do the transactional replication since my on-premise SQL is lied on SQL2008.

Answer (score 2):

You can set infinity as the end of the pipeline:

```
"end": "9999-99-99T12:00:00Z
```

and in Your activity, add

```
"scheduler": {
     "frequency": "Hour",
     "interval": 3
},
```

to set scheduler. I do not see posibility to manually stop pipeline(except restart).

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to do from the description but if the goal is to have it temporarily "not run" you could just pause the Pipeline itself
viz.:

```
"properties": {
        "isPaused": false,
}
```

Set that to "true" in your pipeline and re-deploy and it's paused.  You could then set it back to "false" and unpause it the next day.

Keep in mind that if you have slice activity scheduled during the paused period it will run at the time it's unpaused.